How populate a GTK4 DropDown given a Vec<String>?
I have an application built with gtk4-rs and I would like to create a DropDown and populate it with the items of a Vec<String>. However, I can't find many examples in Rust.
What's the best way to this?
For instance, this is my broken code:
let items: Vec<String> = vec!["Option 1".to_string(), "Option 2".to_string(), "Option 3".to_string()];
let pattern_dropdown = gtk::DropDown::from_strings(items);

But it doesn't compile because:
mismatched types
expected reference `&[&str]`
      found struct `Vec<std::string::String>`

